# get information from page facebook api graph

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I would like to get the information shown in image below from my facebook page (Most Popular Week, Most Popular City, Most Popular Age Group) with FQL.

[image]

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? Any search/research on this yet?

Comment: yes but hi not worked $this->request->data['Pag']['idpage']= $result[0]['id'];
                $params = array('method' => 'fql.query',
                        'query' =>  "SELECT pic,type,name,about,current_location,unread_message_count FROM page WHERE page_id='".$result[0]['id']."'",);
                $result = $facebook->api($params);

Answer (score 2):

For a facebook page you can query the following Graph API endpoint:
graph.facebook.com/{page-id}/insights

Or via FQL:

```
SELECT ... FROM insights WHERE object_id = <page-id> AND metric = B AND end_time = C AND period = D
```

The Most popular City (page_impressions_by_city_unique) and Most popular Age Group (page_impressions_by_age_gender_unique) metrics are reported as unique values from the Insights API Endpoint.

Most popular Week is not reported by the API as far as I can see. You would need to query the API for weekly statistics and compare these in your application code.

You should probably check the documentation yourself: 
Graph API: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/insights/ 
FQL: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/insights